# How To Implement Analytics BD using NO-SQL engine?

Tags: database, data-mining, analysis, olap, nosql

I would love to implement a noSQL data base for a credit entity. I wonder if it's possible implementing analysis methods such as OLAP in (redis, mongo, cassandra, couch or anyother) or data mining, if so? which tools, programs whatever may help me?